# What makes someone a Ba'al Tekiah?

Tags: shofar

Are there any qualifications for being considered a Ba'al Tekiah?  Need one complete a measure of learning on the subject?

Comment: At lease he should learn these laws https://www.chabad.org/3376122/ and maybe also the previous chapters

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102414/discussion-on-question-by-meliorate-what-makes-someone-a-baal-tekiah).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should a neophyte learn to play the shofar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/how-should-a-neophyte-learn-to-play-the-shofar)